# Kotlin unit not returning string

Tags: android, lambda, parse-platform, kotlin

The second parameter of this code must be a string and both email and currentGroup are not null or empty. when I use the normal if else statement, it works. But when i use kotlin lambdas i get an error. I also tried to add `.toString()` at the end of the second parameter but had no luck.

```
query.whereEqualTo("currentGroup",{
    if (isAdmin) email else currentGroup
})
```

I also tried to log the second parameter and got this output:
`Function0<java.lang.String>`

Comment: The second parameter is a lambda... this is what `{}` is. Try removing it. Why do you want to use a lambda? There doesn't seem to be a need for one here.

Comment: In fact its more of my curiosity. I want to return a string from a lambda unit.

Comment: Well then use a function that accepts a lambda and returns a value, like `run` (or invoke it yourself with `()`). You're not going to be able to "convert" a lambda to a string.

Comment: thanks. puttling `run` in front of my unit worked. you can post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your last comment it is clear that your second parameter of your function is a `String`, so either use a `String` directly or call your lambda, e.g.:

```
query.whereEqualTo("currentGroup",{
  if (isAdmin) email else currentGroup
}()) // see the ()? Alternatively/Preferably you may use run {} here, as it is already an inline function (see below)
```

But it is definitely easier to just use `if`-`else` here... you do not gain something from introducing lambdas which are just immediately executed:

```
query.whereEqualTo("currentGroup",
  if (isAdmin) email else currentGroup
)
```

Note also that many functions use [`inline`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#inline-functions) just to overcome the runtime penalties associated with lambdas... so you may want to read about that too before you start liking lambdas and use it everywhere.